# Why doesn't this Python code work? It returns no output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a basketball game that runs in the console, telling the user their points when scored and its distance. Here is the code:

```
game = False

gameStart = input('Press any button to play. ')
gameStartAnswers = ' qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm,./;’[]    \=-0`123456789~!@£$%^&*()_+{}|:”<>?QWERTYIUOPASDFGHJKLZXVBNM'

if gameStart in gameStartAnswers:
    game == True

else:
    print('Invalid input.')
    game == False
```

The problem is that nothing (useful) prints in the console, only either a blank line or:

```
Invalid input.
```

Please explain in detail how to fix this.

Comment: `=` and `==` do 2 different things

Comment: `game == True` is an equality comparison, not an assignment.

Comment: @DeepSpace wow that gave me a good chuckle.

Comment: Bonus:

 - Checking the return value of `input` against every character on your keyboard is redundant, weird and not robust. Also, someone with another locale may find it weird that your program says "press any key" then be shown "invalid input` when they type a character you didn't think of (say, a German character).

 - `if var == True` is both redundant **and** wrong. Just do `if var:` or if you want to be very explicit, `if var is True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This block of code is not doing what you expect:

```
if gameStart in gameStartAnswers:
    game == True

else:
    print('Invalid input.')
    game == False
```

When you use `game == True`, you are *evaluating* whether game is true; you are not *assigning* game to be true.

Use `game = True` instead.

Comment: Shouldn't there be at least a warning like `warning: equality comparison result unused [-Wunused-comparison]` or a note like `note: use '=' to turn this equality comparison into an assignment`? What could be the reason behind not having a small warning?

Comment: @Ayxan If you are using a half-decent IDE you *will* get an `unused statement` warning. If you are asking why this is not a warning at the interpreter level, I don't see any reason why it should be, and I don't think this was trivial to implement even if someone wanted to. Remember that Python is not (usually) compiled and that code is parsed line-by-line. The interpreter does not even detect references to undefined names until it is too late

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks for the explanation! Using [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html) I got 0 warnings. Are these warnings a built-in thing? Is it possible to enable them on IDLE?

Comment: @Ayxan I don't know. Google it